# Is there a way to do this with a formula?

Tags: excel

```
Input: 0 to 100
for 0 = 100
for 1 = prior value (100) + (50 * 1) = 150
for 2 = prior value (150) + (50 * 2) = 250
```

This is easy to do in a table with 0 to 100 in column 1 and a formula that takes the value above it and adds 50 * the current index.

This also works:

if I want the answer for 10, fill in A1 through A10 with 50 and this formula gives the right answer:

```
=100+SUMPRODUCT(A1:A10,ROW(A1:A10))
```

What I am trying to figure out: 
Can I do this in a single cell that tells me the output for a given row? 
I want the formula to look at a ref cell for the input and provide the cumulative total of 50*index up to that input, plus 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup:

Put 100 in A1 and the number of iterations in A2:

```
=A1+SUMPRODUCT(50*ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & A2)))
```

[image]

Comment: I get #VALUE!     I tried to just type in 
      =SUMPRODUCT(50,ROW(INDIRECT("1:10")))  and that also gave me the error.

Comment: @JustinMcCartney see the edit, I replace the `,` with the `*`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a UDF (User Defined Function) solution:

```
Function myFunc(rng As Range) As Long

    Dim lastRng As Range
    Set lastRng = Cells(rng.Row - 1, rng.Column + 1)

    myFunc = lastRng + (50 * rng.Row)

End Function
```

You can then use the formula `=myFunc(A1)` in your worksheet.